# AngularJS: Error: The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to filter the list of records using date(in milliseconds). I tried this

**HTML**

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDateFilter" ng-change="dateFilter(myDateFilter)" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.myDateFilter = new Date().getTime();

    $scope.dateFilter = function (dt) {
      $scope.myDateFilter = new Date(dt).getTime();
    }
    $scope.dateFilter($scope.myDateFilter);
```

getting this error in console

```
angular.js:13920 Error: The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: number
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular-material.js:28134)
    at ngModelWatch (angular.js:27810)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17515)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17790)
    at done (angular.js:11831)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12033)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11966)
```

Help me what is causing issue.

Comment: It's because getTime returns number, and ng-model expects Date. what are you trying to do?

Comment: try removing the two ".getTime();"